# Can you granularly control what comes over the SCOM CI connector in SCSM 2012?

Tags: windows, system-center, scsm-2012, scom

In System Center Service Manager 2012 SP1, is it possible to granularly control what comes over the SCOM CI connector into the CMDB?

For example, to get an AIX computer across the connector, you [have to whitelist](http://blogs.technet.com/b/servicemanager/archive/2011/10/05/unix-linux-management-in-scsm-new-unix-linux-computer-form-mp-released.aspx) the following classes using `Add-SCSMAllowListClass`:

```
Microsoft.Unix.LogicalDevice
Microsoft.Linux.Computer
Microsoft.Unix.AIX.6.1.Computer
etc
```

This also brings in all of the peripheral information from those computers as CIs, such as network adapters, logical disks, etc.

Is there a way to just bring the computer CI over the connector and leave the related items behind, or does it have to come over all at once?

Answer (score 1):

You might find this helpful: [Managing Allowed List for the CI Connector](https://blogs.technet.com/b/servicemanager/archive/2010/02/26/managing-the-allowed-list-for-the-operations-manager-ci-connector-with-powershell.aspx)